# Connect Sqoop to Hadoop in Pyspark

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, sqoop

This is the code I am using on Pyspark. I am currently trying to connect Sqoop to HDFS.
I am new to all this. I am not sure what libraries to use.

```
from pysqoop.SqoopImport import Sqoop
sqoop = Sqoop(help=True)
code = sqoop.perform_import()


sqoop = Sqoop(fs='hdfs://localhost:8020', table='myTable', target_dir='hdfs://user/amel',
connect='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb',
username='Amel', password='Amel@-1998', num_mappers=2,
bindir='/usr/local/hadoop/sqoop/bin')

sqoop.perform_import()
```

This is the error

```
/home/amel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /home/amel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Hello.py
sqoop import None  --help 
name 'run' is not defined
sqoop import None  -fs hdfs://localhost:8020 --table myTable --target-dir hdfs://user/amel --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb --username Amel --password Amel@-1998 --num-mappers 2 --bindir /usr/local/hadoop/sqoop/bin --help 
name 'run' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### NOTICE

Sqoop has been retired as an Apache project, and Spark **can replace** Sqoop. You should not be using them together.

---

In any case, that `pysqoop` library appears to be broken and no one has seemed to commit a PR to fix it it in over a year (although, I did). It obviously doesn't have unit-tests to catch that error, so I would not suggest using it in its current form.

---

Here's an example of sections copied from the Spark documentation for reading JDBC databases and writing to HDFS as Parquet

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SqoopReplacement").getOrCreate()

jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306") \
    .option("dbtable", "myTable") \
    .option("user", "Amel") \
    .option("password", "Amel@-1998") \
    .load()

# Saving data to HDFS as Parquet
jdbcDF.write.parquet("hdfs://some/path")
```

Comment: Sir does this mean I can no longer use sqoop? okay, I will implement this code and let you know. Thank you for helping me, I'm working on my thesis project.

Comment: Unclear why you need to use `sqoop` binary when there are other valid options that work for this same use-case

Comment: @OneCricketeer Isn't Spark an overkill for this use-case? Wouldn't sqoop be a more lightweight and better option for just data transfer?

Comment: @GiorgosSkourtsidis Sqoop is a retired Apache project, as answered. OP already said "using code on pyspark"